# Remove a particular field for all documents in a collection using aggregation in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregate-functions, aggregation

How to Remove a particular value for all records in the collection using aggregation :

Have a collection with data :

```
[
 {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    present_working:true,
    age: 55,
    location: "texas"

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    present_working:false,
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    location: "texas",
    present_working:false
  }
]
```

Remove the rows in records for which there is `present_working:false`. Data need not be removed in the database, it should be only modified in the aggregation pipeline

Expected output after removing only `present_working:false` and `present_working:false` should be kept in database. :

```
[
 {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    present_working:true,
    age: 55,
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

MongoDB version: **4.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$$REMOVE` [as part of $project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields-conditionally):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            occupation: 1,
            age: 1,
            location: 1,
            present_working: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$present_working", false ] }, "$$REMOVE", "$present_working" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qYlLbjGp2CA)